# Hide or remove unwanted strings from windows executable release

Tags: c++, string, reference, executable

I have this habit always a C++ project is compiled and the release is built up. I always open the .EXE with a hexadecimal editor (usually HxD) and have a look at the binary information.

What I hate most and try to find a solution for is the fact that somewhere in the string table, relevant (at least, from my point of view) information is offered. Maybe for other people this sounds like a schizophrenia obsession but I just don't like when my executable contains, for example, the names of all the Windows functions used in the application.

I have tried many compilers to see which of them published the least information. For example, GCC leaves all this in all of its produced final exe

```
libgcj_s.dll._Jv_RegisterClasses....\Data.ald.rb.Error.Data file is corrupt!
....Data for the application not found!.€.@.ř.@.0.@.€.@.°.@.p.@.p.@.p.@.p.@.
¸.@.$.@.€.@°.@.std::bad_alloc..__gnu_cxx::__concurrence_lock_error.__gnu_cxx
::__concurrence_unlock_error...std::exception.std::bad_exception...pure virt
ual method called..../../runtime/pseudo-reloc.c....VirtualQuery (addr, &b, s
ize of(b))............................/../../../gcc-4.4.1/libgcc/../gcc/conf    
ig/i386/cygming-shared-data.c...0 && "Couldn't retrieve name of GCClib share
d data atom"....ret->size == sizeof(__cygming_shared) && "GCClib shared data
 size mismatch".0 && "Couldn't add GCClib shared data atom".....-GCCLIBCYGMI
NG-EH-TDM1-SJLJ-GTHR-MINGW32........
```

Here, you can see what compiler I used, and what version. Now, a few lines below you can see a  list with every Windows function I used, like CreateMainWindow, GetCurrentThreadId, etc.

I wonder if there are ways of not displaying this, or encrypting, obfuscating it.

With Visual C++ this information is not published. Instead, it is not so cross-platform as GCC, which even between two Windows systems like 7 and XP, doesn't need C++ run-time, frameworks or whatever programs compiled with VC++ need. Moreover, the VC++ executables also contain those procedures entry points to the Windows functions used in the application.

I know that even NASM, for example, saves the name of the called Windows functions, so it looks like it's a Windows issue. But maybe they can be encrypted or there's some trick to not show them.

I will have a look over the GCC source code to see where are those strings specified to be saved in the executables - maybe that instruction can be skipped or something.

Well, this is one of my last paranoia and maybe it can be treated some way. Thanks for your opinions and answers.

Comment: How do you think the dynamic linker is able to find which win32 functions it needs to link into your program? You'll have a hard time removing or hiding that information while still having a program that runs.

Comment: A crazy solution is to distribute every required DLL (even Windows DLL's) with the executable and try to encrypt or obfuscate any referenced function in the DLL and also in the EXE. I don't know if that is a non-sense.

Comment: Yes, that's nonsense. If you did that, you'd break every other application on every machine you installed your application on - what would be the point? Write your own operating system instead, and sell dedicated hardware/OS/application, if that's what you want. Trying to hide standard Win32 API calls your app makes is a waste of time and effort, IMO. "Gee, this app calls GetLastError and has the string 'pure virtual function called' in it!!!! Oh, no!". There are a billion better ways to spend your time and effort on than worrying about this stuff.

Comment: Let's roll this question back to the beginning: What are you trying to acomplish?  Many of the strings you're complaining about appear to be asserts and __FILE__ entries from the C runtime library you're using.  Are you linking against a debug C runtime library?  That would explain the strings.

Comment: @bames53: The dynamic linker can use **ordinals** (numbers) instead of names.

Comment: Well people, thanks to everybody. At least, other users that may be as maniacs as me when talking about security know now that you can never protect your executables the 100%, because they must be describable bunches of bytes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows API functions are loaded from dlls, like kernel32.dll.  In order to get the loaded API function's memory address, a table of exported function names from the dll is searched.  Thus the presence of these names.

You could manually load any Windows API functions you reference with LoadLibrary. The you could look up the functions' addresses with GetProcAddress and functions names stored in some obfuscated form.  Alternately, you could use each function's "ordinal" -- a numeric value that identifies each function in a dll).  This way, you could create a set of function pointers that you will use to call API functions.

But, to really make it clean, you would probably have to turn off linking of default libraries and replace components of the C Runtime library that are implicitly used by the compiler.  Doing this is a hasslse, though.

Comment: If I have the kernel32 source code (which I don't think is open source) I can re-name/obfuscate functions names and re-build the DLL. That sounds like crazy, for sure.

Comment: @ali, `Kernel32` is indeed closed-source (it's part of the basic Win32 kernel); if you renamed the functions in it and recompiled, you'd break every Windows machine you installed your app on. Also, the problem with linking using ordinals is that there's no guarantee they'll stay the same in future Windows versions.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile with `-nostdlib` then the GCC stuff should go away but you also lose some of the C++ support and std::*.

On Windows you can create an application that only links to `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` and at runtime it can get the rest of the functions you need (The names of the functions can be stored in encrypted form and you decrypt the string before passing it to GetProcAddress) Doing this is a lot of work and the Windows loader is probably faster at this than your code is going to be so it seems pointless to me to obfuscate the fact that you are calling simple functions like `GetLastError` and `CreateWindow`.

Comment: Yes, maybe there's no problem with essential Windows functions that are required in any exe, but I can try that with my DLLs. Yes, I tried -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib and I got an Assembly compiler